# C- fgets() erasing user input

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to collect user input but my "Title" is getting wiped out.  If I comment out the fgets for "Rating" and "Year" it doesn't get wiped out.  I don't understand why?

Also, when using fgets my int is not correct output (see output).  But if I use scanf it is.  Why is that?

**MOVIE.C**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "movie.h"

    void print_movie(const movie_t * mvi) {
        printf("Title:%s", mvi->title);
        printf("Director:%s", mvi->director);
        printf("Rating:%c\n", mvi->rating);
        printf("Year: %d\n", mvi->year);
    }

    void get_movie(movie_t * mvi) {
        printf("Title:");
        fgets(&mvi->title, 50, stdin);
        printf("Enter Director Name:");
        fgets(&mvi->director, 50, stdin);
        printf("Enter Movie Rating:");
        fgets(&mvi->rating,5, stdin);
        printf("Enter Movie Year:");
        fgets(&mvi->year, 5, stdin);
        //scanf will output correct year
        //scanf("%d",&mvi->year);
    }
```

**MOVIE.H**

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define MOVIE_H
#define SIZE_LIMIT 25
#define RATING_SIZE 5

typedef enum {G, PG, PG13, R} rating_t;

typedef struct {
    char rating;
    char title[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char director[SIZE_LIMIT];
    int year;
}movie_t;


void get_movie(movie_t * movie);
void print_movie(const movie_t * movie);

#endif /* MOVIE_H
```

**MAIN.C**

```
#include "movie.h"

int main(){ 
movie_t movie;
movie.year = 0;
get_movie(&movie);
print_movie(&movie);
return 0;
}
```

- INPUT

Title:Batman
Enter Director Name:Spielberg
Enter Movie Rating:R
Enter Movie Year:2000

- OUTPUT

Title:
Director:Spielberg
Rating:R
Year: 808464434

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this:

```
#define SIZE_LIMIT 25
//                 ^^

fgets(&mvi->title, 50, stdin);
//                 ^^
```

Just use SIZE_LIMIT instead of 50.

(You should also use `mvi->title` or `&mvi->title[0]` instead of `&mvi->title`, otherwise you have  a type error... are you including the right headers?)

Also, these are completely wrong:

```
fgets(&mvi->rating,5, stdin);
fgets(&mvi->year, 5, stdin);
```

You'll probably want to use `scanf()` or something instead.  The `fgets()` function reads strings, but neither `rating` nor `year` is a string.  That's why `scanf()` works correctly, because you can use `scanf()` to read integers.

### Why 808464434?

Because 808464434 is the string "2000" interpreted as an integer, 0x30303032.  0x30 is the character '0' in ASCII, and 0x32 is the character '2' in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks man that worked!  Just to put it in simple terms for simple people like me on your explanation of `Why 808464434`.  To make sure I understand, the hexadecimal representation of the ASCII string "2000" is 0x30303032 and when that is converted to decimal, it is equal to 808464434?  The only part I'm still a hair confused on is why the hex value is represented from left to right?  I tried googling a few articles but not sure I'm searching for the right term, 'decimal to hex'?

Comment: @mdo123: You're using a little-endian processor, so when you store the number `0x01020304` to memory, it gets written as `0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01`.  Some processors are big-endian, they go the opposite way.

Comment: And I'd just like to clarify that it's never actually written in hex... hex is just how I write things out on Stack Overflow for clarity.  The actual memory is stored as raw bytes.